# Merge two JSON into one JSON using Java and validate in karate feature file

Tags: java, karate

`Json1 {"key1" :"one","key2":"two"}`
`Json2 {"FN": "AB","LN":"XY"}`
I wish to have Json3 `{"key1" :"one","key2":"two","FN": "AB","LN":"XY"}`

I have used below code but it does not work:

```
        JSONObject mergedJSON = new JSONObject();
        try {
            mergedJSON = new JSONObject(json1, JSONObject.getNames(json1));
            for (String Key : JSONObject.getNames(json2)) {
                mergedJSON.put(Key, json2.get(Key));
            }
 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
 
            throw new RuntimeException("JSON Exception" + e);
        }
        return mergedJSON;
    }

      * call defaultCOM {ID: "COM-123"}
        * def defaultResponse = response.data.default
        * def jMap = mergeJSON.toMap(defaultResponse)
Here error comes (language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.graal.JsMap) to Java type 'org.json.JSONObject': Unsupported target type
```

Comment: I removed the `karate` tag. in my honest opinion you should never need to use `JSONObject` when using karate

Comment: Ahh Peter. I hit submit button soon. Sincerely sorry. Above Json response is coming form API. ```* call defaultCOM {ID: "abc-123"}
  * def defaultResponse = response.data.default
  * json jMap = mergeJSON.toMap(defaultResponse)```    and when I call above mentioned Java method is feature file I get below error invokeMember (toMap) on com.basicUtil.mergeJSONObject failed due to: Cannot convert '{"key1":"one","key2":"two"(language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.graal.JsMap) to Java type 'org.json.JSONObject': Unsupported target

Comment: well ok. whatever java code you have there is not something I spent much time on trying to understand. I have added an answer, that's all I can help with

Answer (score 1):

All I'll say is that the recommended way to merge 2 JSONs is given in the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms

```
* def foo = { a: 1 }
* def bar = karate.merge(foo, { b: 2 })
* match bar == { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

I'll also say that when you use custom Java code, you should stick to using `Map` or `List`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java

And if you use things like `JSONObject` whatever that is, you are on your own - and please consider that not supported by Karate.

When you have to mix Java and the Karate-style JS code (and this something you should try to avoid as far as possible) you need to be aware of some caveats: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#js-to-java

Comment: Thank you @Peter. It gives me clue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just don't care about key collisions this should work:

```
String jsons01 = "{\"key1\" :\"one\",\"key2\":\"two\"}";
String jsons02 = "{\"FN\": \"AB\",\"LN\":\"XY\"}";
JSONObject jsono01 = new JSONObject(jsons01);
JSONObject jsono02 = new JSONObject(jsons02);
JSONObject merged = new JSONObject(jsono01, Object.getNames(jsono01));
for (String key : JSONObject.getNames(jsono02)) {
    merged.append(key, jsono02.get(key));
}
System.out.println(merged);
```

Result is: `{"key1":"one","FN":["AB"],"key2":"two","LN":["XY"]}`